# How to avoid redundant type and instance of type in widget constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a wrapper which takes two arguments: a model and a screen.

This wrapper uses `ChangeNotifierProvider<T>` internally, `T` being the model type.

Calling this wrapper widget at the moment looks like this:

```dart
NotifierWrapper<Preferences>(Preferences(), PreferencesScreen());
```

The above works, but it's verbose and redundant and frankly bad API design.

This is the wrapper widget:

```dart
class NotifierWrapper<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatelessWidget {

  final T _model;
  final _screen;

  NotifierWrapper(this._model, this._screen);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      builder: (_) => _model,
      child: _screen
    );
  }
}
```

I want this API to look like:

```dart
NotifierWrapper(Preferences(), PreferencesScreen());
```

But this does not work as `ChangeNotifierProvider<T>` requires a type. Can I provide a type to `ChangeNotifierProvider` from an instance of `T`?

Something like this (and variants) fail:

```dart
// ...
Type<ChangeNotifier> T = _model.runtimeType;
return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
// ...
```

or otherwise

```dart
NotifierWrapper<Preferences>(PreferencesScreen());
```

Deriving a constructor from a type?

```dart
// ...
return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
  builder: (_) => T()
// ...
```

If these are not possible as I fear, how can I provide a sane API design in this case?

Tell me there is a way to avoid supplying type `Preferences` and a instance of `Preferences()` at the same time!

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you use `NotifierWrapper(Preferences(), PreferencesScreen());`?  I would expect `T` to be inferred from the `Preferences()` argument.

Comment: @jamesdlin You're right, that works! Not sure how I mixed up during my tests and thought it didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does NOT work. In my comment above I checked and had no compilation errors, but it fails at runtime with  "Could not find the correct Provider<Preferences> above this PreferencesScreen Widget".  When I specify the type via `NotifierWrapper<Preferences>(...)` it does work correctly in the app. The bliss of static typing...

Comment: When you use `NotifierWrapper(Preferences(), ...)`, what is the actual type of the constructed `NotifierWrapper`?

Comment: @jamesdlin It's `NotifierWrapper<Preferences>` , I don't get why `ChangeNotifierProvider<T>` is not "registering" as `ChangeNotifierProvider<Preferences>`